# Can Apache processes ignore USR1 signal?

Tags: apache-2.2

We're doing a graceful restart of our Apache server processes on the first day of every month. Usually it works fine. But this month one of our servers seemed to ignore that. We noticed it because the first few days of December were missing from the log files (which are NEW log files, the old ones being deleted after the graceful restart). This would be expected if the Apache processes ignored the graceful restart (i.e. the USR1 signal sent from Apache parent to all of its children) and kept on running, writing to the old (i.e. now deleted) log files. But the documentation ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/stopping.html ) does not say anything about ignoring the signal and I don't know what circumstances would lead to that. Since the documentation says the USR1 signal `advise[s] the children to exit after their current request`, I guess ignoring it possible. The affected Apache is version 2.2.31.

Comment: Ignoring most a signal is ofc. possibe. The process gets the signal and decides what do do with it. (well, barring a few like kill -9 SIGKILL). But if it is the same version of appache as the others with the same configuration then that is strange. If there anything in the old log files (those are NOT deleted if appache still has an open handle to them, they are just removed from the directory listing and will be deleted once no files are using them anymore.)

Comment: @Hennes. Maybe I shouldn't have asked whether it CAN be ignored, but rather why it would do that. But I don't like to put assumptions into a question and right now I am still unsure whether ignoring the signal was really the problem - it just seems like it.